# XSLT : Nested Loops, If Condition

Tags: xsl-fo

I am new to XSL-FO and XPATH and have difficult in achieving the following requirement. My Requirement is to get results as below from the XML and XSL-FO:

I need to show the results as below

```
Line# Item Description   Quantity  LINE_ARRIVAL_DATE
1      test PO print-1     15      30-AUG-2016
2      test PO print-2     25      30-SEP-2016
```

As you see the `Line #`, `Item Description` and `Quantity` come from `PO_DATA/LINES/LINES_ROW/` information and `LINE_ARRIVAL_DATE` comes from `PO_DATA/PURCHASEORDER/LINE_REF/PO_LINE_TYPE` 
and the only way they are related is by the `PO_LINE_ID`  in `LINES_ROW` and `PO_LINE_TYPE` XML parents.
I thought having 2 for-each but that is not helping and I am not able to do for-each with the XSL-FO (below) and maybe my lack of knowledge on XSL-FO is the constraint.
Please let me know if I can achieve this requirement and also of how I could achieve this.

Thanks for looking.

```
<PO_DATA>
    <SEGMENT1>321178</SEGMENT1>
    <LINES>
        <LINES_ROW>
            <LINE_NUM>1</LINE_NUM>
            <ITEM_DESCRIPTION>test PO print-1</ITEM_DESCRIPTION>
            <CANCEL_FLAG>N</CANCEL_FLAG>
            <UNIT_MEAS_LOOKUP_CODE>EACH</UNIT_MEAS_LOOKUP_CODE>
            <ORDER_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE>QUANTITY</ORDER_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE>
            <UNIT_PRICE>25</UNIT_PRICE>
            <QUANTITY>15</QUANTITY>
            <PO_HEADER_ID>408363</PO_HEADER_ID>
            <PO_LINE_ID>697709</PO_LINE_ID>
        </LINES_ROW>
        <LINES_ROW>
            <LINE_NUM>2</LINE_NUM>
            <ITEM_DESCRIPTION>test PO print-2</ITEM_DESCRIPTION>
            <CANCEL_FLAG>N</CANCEL_FLAG>
            <UNIT_MEAS_LOOKUP_CODE>EACH</UNIT_MEAS_LOOKUP_CODE>
            <ORDER_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE>QUANTITY</ORDER_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE>
            <UNIT_PRICE>25</UNIT_PRICE>
            <QUANTITY>15</QUANTITY>
            <PO_HEADER_ID>408363</PO_HEADER_ID>
            <PO_LINE_ID>697710</PO_LINE_ID>
        </LINES_ROW>  
    </LINES>
    <PURCHASEORDER>
            <PO_HEADER_ID>408363</PO_HEADER_ID>
            <LINE_REF>
                <POLINE_TYP>
                    <PO_LINE_ID>697709</PO_LINE_ID>
                    <LINE_ARRIVAL_DATE>30-AUG-2016</LINE_ARRIVAL_DATE>
                </POLINE_TYP>   
                <POLINE_TYP>
                    <PO_LINE_ID>697710</PO_LINE_ID>
                    <LINE_ARRIVAL_DATE>30-SEP-2016</LINE_ARRIVAL_DATE>
                </POLINE_TYP>   
            </LINE_REF>    
    </PURCHASEORDER>  
</PO_DATA>
```

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My PO Lines</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Line #</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Item Description</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">spolineid</th>      
        <th style="text-align:left">cpolineid</th>      
        <th style="text-align:left">comparison</th>     
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="PO_DATA/LINES/LINES_ROW">
      <!--xsl:for-each select="PURCHASEORDER/LINE_REF"-->     
      <!--xsl:for-each select="PURCHASEORDER/LINE_REF/POLINE_TYP"-->          
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="LINE_NUM"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="ITEM_DESCRIPTION"/></td>
        <!--xsl:variable name="spolineid" select="string(PO_LINE_ID)"/>     
        <td><xsl:value-of select="$spolineid" /></td>
        <xsl:variable name="cpolineid" select="string(../../PURCHASEORDER/LINE_REF/POLINE_TYP/PO_LINE_ID)"/>        
        <td><xsl:value-of select="$cpolineid" /></td>
        <td><xsl:if test = "$spolineid = $cpolineid "> <xsl:value-of select="../../PURCHASEORDER/LINE_REF/POLINE_TYP/LINE_ARRIVAL_DATE"/></xsl:if></td-->

         <td><xsl:for-each select="PO_DATA/PURCHASEORDER/LINE_REF/POLINE_TYP">
                <xsl:value-of select="LINE_ARRIVAL_DATE"/>
                </xsl:for-each></td>        

        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <!--/xsl:for-each-->    
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following stylesheet will work if you are using XSLT 1.0 processor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My PO Lines</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th style="text-align:left">Line #</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Item Description</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Quantity</th>      
                        <th style="text-align:left">LINE_ARRIVAL_DATE</th> 
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="PO_DATA/LINES/LINES_ROW">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="LINE_NUM"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="ITEM_DESCRIPTION"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="QUANTITY"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="(/PO_DATA/PURCHASEORDER/LINE_REF/POLINE_TYP[string(PO_LINE_ID) = string(current()/PO_LINE_ID)]/LINE_ARRIVAL_DATE)[1]"/>
                            </td>        
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For your reference I added more elegant xsl:key and key() solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:key name="LINE" match="/PO_DATA/PURCHASEORDER/LINE_REF/POLINE_TYP" use="PO_LINE_ID"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>My PO Lines</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th style="text-align:left">Line #</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Item Description</th>
                        <th style="text-align:left">Quantity</th>      
                        <th style="text-align:left">LINE_ARRIVAL_DATE</th> 
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="PO_DATA/LINES/LINES_ROW">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="LINE_NUM"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="ITEM_DESCRIPTION"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="QUANTITY"/></td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="(key('LINE',PO_LINE_ID)/LINE_ARRIVAL_DATE)[1]"/>
                            </td>        
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Above two XSLT stylesheets are tested via XSLT 1.0 processor Saxon 6.5.5 and MSXML.

Comment: Since there is only one `POLINE_TYP` element (that we know about), the `xsl:key/@match` could just be `match="POLINE_TYP"`.  If `POLINE_TYP/PO_LINE_ID` values are unique, then the "`(...)[1]`" in the `@select` is not needed since there would only ever be one.  It comes down to how defensive you want to be about possibly irregular input.

Comment: Yes, I have been told from users such like “The element is unique” or “It appears exactly once”. However when I use the strict type system declaration in XSLT 2.0. I often encounter the XSLT processor’s runtime error message that the precondition such as as=”element()” has been broken by actual input data.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the response here. It really helped to get my requirement accomplished. One thing I noticed is that I was using XML Notepad to initially run this but realized that eq function is not present in XML Notepad and hence couldn't use it. Nevertheless this requirement worked in Oracle E-business suite.

Comment: What editor did you use to see this output correctly , since I was not able to see it working through XML Notepad. Thanks

Comment: I am using oXygen 18.0 and Saxon 9.6. From your comment I guess you are using XSLT 1.0 processor. So I modified full code example for it. Hope it works in Oracle E-business suite.